# Inverse Fourier Transform of $ (j\omega)\cdot \frac{1}{a+j\omega} $

Tags: fourier-transform, data-analysis

We are trying to find the inverse Fourier Transform of $$ (j\omega) \cdot \frac{1}{(a+j\omega)} $$

For this we would obviously need to use Fourier transform pairs / equations

$ e^{-at} \cdot u(t), a > 0 \xrightarrow{\text{X(j$\omega$)}} \frac{1}{(a+j\omega)} \tag 1$

$ t \xrightarrow{\text{X(j$\omega$)}} j\omega \tag 2$

However, we disagree that equation (2) holds true for this situation. If it does, this would then yield $x(t) = t \cdot e^{-at} \cdot u(t) $. We have difficulty understanding if htis would hold applicable or not: any helpful thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: $j$ is the imaginary unit?

Comment: Yes,rather than i most engineering studies, domains and related fields use j as the imaginary unit

Comment: do you know what *convolution theorem of Fourier transform* is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by stating the convolution theorem:

$$\text{For $f,g$ functions we have: } \begin{align}\mathcal F(f\cdot g)=\mathcal F(f)*\mathcal F(g)\\\mathcal F(f* g)=\mathcal F(f)\cdot\mathcal F(g)\end{align}$$

This can be extended to the inverse easily:

$$\mathcal F^{-1}=R\mathcal F=\mathcal FR;\text{ where $R$ is flip operator}$$
Hence
$$\text{For $f,g$ functions we have: } \begin{align}\mathcal F^{-1}(f\cdot g)=\mathcal F(Rf\cdot Rg)=\mathcal F(Rf)*\mathcal F(Rg)=\mathcal F^{-1}(f)*\mathcal F^{-1}(g)\\\mathcal F^{-1}(f* g)=\mathcal F(Rf* Rg)=\mathcal F(Rf)\cdot\mathcal F(Rg)=\mathcal F^{-1}(f)\cdot\mathcal F^{-1}(g)\end{align}$$

We have $2$ functions: $f=j\omega, g=\frac{1}{a+j\omega}$

We can calculate to see that $\mathcal F^{-1}(f)=\mathcal F(Rf)=\mathcal F((-jw)^1\cdot1)=\delta'(t)$(I don't know where you got your value but it was wrong)

Unless I did a stupid mistake in my calculation, the inverse fourier transform of $g$ is exactly what you got.

Because we take the inverse of the product we change it to the convolution of the inverse:

$$\mathcal F^{-1}\left(j\omega\cdot\frac1{a+j\omega}\right)=\left(\delta'(t)*(e^{-at} \cdot u(t))\right)=\dfrac d{dt}\left(e^{-at} \cdot u(t)\right)=\delta(t)-au(t)e^{-at}$$(assuming, ofc, that $a>0$)

---

## Edit

It is important to point out, this is **without normalization**. Because I don't know from where the function you have got I can't tell if we need normalization, and if yes which one. The $2$ most common normalizations are: dividing by $2\pi$ only at the inverse or dividing by $\sqrt{2\pi}$ both on the forward and at the inverse fourier transform

Comment: I added a little information about normalization

Comment: This absolutely makes more sense then my approach using $ j\omega \rightarrow t $: how did you obtain the (inverse) Fourier Transform of $ j\omega $? To solve such equations we mostly refer to Fourier Transform tables, but we were not able to find the corresponding transfer pair for $ j\omega $ (obviously). We therefore concluded that if it was not listed, it would probably be so simple it would not need listing: seeing as we go from the time $ x(t) $ domain to the frequency $ X(jw) $ domain it would make sense that $$ t \xrightarrow{\text{X(j$\omega$)}} j\omega \tag 2 $$

Comment: @Nanne118 I would argue that it is the simplest! You just don't used to it so it looks complicated. Notice: $$X(j\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\implies \dfrac{d}{d\omega} X(j\omega)=\dfrac{d}{d\omega}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)\dfrac{d}{d\omega}e^{-j\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overbrace{x(t)(-j\omega)}^{\text{this is your function}}e^{-j\omega t}dt=(-j\omega)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$, set $x(t)=1$ and you get that $\mathcal F^{-1}(j\omega)=\mathcal F(-j\omega)=\dfrac{d}{d\omega}\mathcal F(1)$